# The word @drawable is not correctly spelled

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a styles.xml file with the following in it:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_b</item>
</style>
```

I get the error `The @drawable is not correctly spelled'.`actionbar_b' file is on its place.

Comment: You are missing the @ on the parent element, that should be @android:style/[..]. Maybe the parser chokes on that.

Answer (score 17):

in Eclipse go to Window/preferences/Editors/text editors/spelling and remove check from "Enable check spelling"

Answer (score 0):

The style file "styles.xml" must be start with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
```

and finish with:

```
</resources>
```

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>  
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_b</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I forgot to write the .xml extension of the created file.

Answer (score -3):

You can ignore the error. It will build anyway.